# Validation for element in a loop

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm having trouble with validating every single PhoneNumber Textbox in a for loop. 
My validation function works well with single Texbox, but when I try to apply to a loop, I don't know how could javascript understand the index for the loop.

Need help!

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
       <td>
         <div>
            <b>Phone Number:</b>
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Hotline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ShortInput", id = "hotline[i]//html doesn't understand the index here"  maxlength = "15" } })
             <span class="ErrorBlock field-validation-valid"></span>
          </div>
         </td>
</tr>
```

This is validation function:

```
function validateForm() {
     var result = true;
     result = checkPhone('#hotLine//"how could I get the index here"', 'Invalid phone number.') && result;
      return result;
        }
```

Comment: Well what you have to do is first get  all elements and you can get those by using a css class and searching elements from classname in jquery and after you get all elements you can use foreach to get all element one by one and validate

Answer (score -1):

It won't recoginize the index in html as it's taking it as a string. What you can do is, inside the loop, make use of var and then assign that var to your id. 
Something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    var dynamicId = "hotline["+@i+"]";
    <tr>
       <td>
         <div>
            <b>Phone Number:</b>
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Hotline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ShortInput", id = dynamicId  maxlength = "15" } })
             <span class="ErrorBlock field-validation-valid"></span>
          </div>
         </td>
</tr>
```

Might have some syntactical error, but this should work.

In jquery, you can do something like this;

```
function validateForm() {
     var result = true;
     $('.ShortInput').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).id; 
    // TODO: whatever operation you want to perform
});
        }
```

Comment: Well that's why I've commented you should do something like this. I didn't knew you wanted exact code upfront and running. You could've tried this with little changes and it would've worked :)